# StreamWriter ReadLine method hangs program

Tags: c#, asynchronous, streamwriter

I am trying to get some basic multi-threading working in C#. There's no clear tutorial that I've found so bear with my sub-par code:

```
class Program
{
    private static TcpListener listener;
    private static List<TcpClient> clients; 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1337);
        clients = new List<TcpClient>();
        StartListening();
        Console.WriteLine("Accepting clients..");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async void StartListening()
    {
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            clients.Add(await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
            HandleClient(clients[clients.Count - 1], clients.Count);
        }
    }

    static async void HandleClient(TcpClient c, int number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Getting client #{number}'s handshake..");
        var ns = c.GetStream();
        var sr = new StreamReader(ns);
        var handshake = sr.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Client {0}'s handshake: {1}", number, handshake);
    }
}
```

Right, so what I'm trying to achieve in the server program is:

```
 1. Accepting client
 2. Receiving handshake, print it to console
 3. Add to the clients list
```

The accepting client part works, however the program just stops just after the first line of `HandleClient()`. I've tried waiting for absurd amounts of time (1000ms) and even then it just doesn't receive anything, nor does it throw an exception (i.e. it stays connected). What am I doing wrong here?

Client code is [here](http://pastebin.com/GZNDHWT0) if you need it!

Comment: You should post the client code that sends data as well since the question is incomplete without it. Seeing as the problem is in the client as well, and not in the server part, then this is all the more important.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I agree!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client code is broken here - you're never flushing it:

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
sw.WriteLine(handshake);
```

There's no need for the `Thread.Sleep` call, but you should flush the `StreamWriter` if you want the data to actually be sent to the network layer immediately:

```
sw.Flush();
```

While (as Stephen Cleary notes) this wouldn't mean it necessarily got sent *immediately*, it's reasonable to expect it to be sent "reasonably soon" after flushing.

Comment: Love you Jon! You're my hero :)

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to get some basic multi-threading working in C#.

I'm always amazed at devs who try to learn concurrency by writing a bare-metal TCP/IP server (when they've never programmed TCP/IP previously). Concurrency and TCP/IP are two extremely difficult topics; trying to learn them at the same time is almost certainly going to end in disaster. It's just really odd that this is such a common approach.

If you want to learn asynchrony, I recommend my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [article on best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (where, among other things, you'll learn the principle "avoid `async void`").

If you want to learn TCP/IP, I recommend my [TCP/IP .NET FAQ blog series](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html). However, writing TCP/IP code is almost never *necessary*, and since you can change both the client and server, I **strongly** recommend using SignalR instead.

I suspect that you actually want to learn `async`, and the TCP/IP is just getting in the way. So, drop the harder topic (TCP/IP) and use `async` with simpler communications such as WebAPI or SignalR.

(As far as the actual problem you saw, it is indeed caused by buffering, but it's important to note that flushing the buffer does not cause the data to be send over the network immediately; it is only sent to the networking *layer* immediately. A proper solution would need message framing.)

Comment: Actually I am writing a multiplayer snake game and so I need both TCP/IP and async :)

Comment: @Ilan321: SignalR works quite well for multiplayer games.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't import any external libraries :(

Comment: @Ilan321: Not sure what you mean. SignalR should suffice as a transport protocol of equal capabilities as TCP/IP.

Comment: I can't physically use any libraries that aren't included in .NET 4.5.. :(

Comment: @Ilan321: 1) That's almost certainly a wrong requirement; your best bet is to push back. 2) SignalR *is* included in .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet mentioned, to make sure the content is not just sitting in a buffer, you should Flush it.

Your client should look like so:

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
Thread.Sleep(1000); // let the server catch up
sw.WriteLine(handshake);
sw.Flush();
Console.WriteLine("Staying connected.. Press ESCAPE to exit.");
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention... That `Thread.Sleep(1000);` there... you can safely remove it.